# PLSQL Format number for display wtihout decimal limitation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem that I am pretty sure is not unique

I have a database column that has values like the following

```
Col
.42
1.2
5
2.222212
```

Now I am appending this column to sent to front end application and need to format it. But I should not be loosing any decimal values too.

So what I would want to send to the front end application would be like

```
0.42
1.2
5.0
2.222212
```

Basically, I dont want to loose out any decimal position. But no trailing zeros should be added more than 1. Similarly, a 0 should be appended before a decimal value that starts with '.' (eg: .42) But not more than 1 leading 0 should be appended.

Breaking my head on this right now. Any help would be sincerly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? The keys are the 0 markers (if no digit would exist there, put in a 0) and the FM (other than what's shown as required - i.e. the units digit, the decimal point and the tenths digit, make the output as narrow as possible).

This assumes the inputs are in NUMBER datatype and the desired output is string (VARCHAR2). If the inputs are strings also, wrap them within `to_number()`.

```
with
     test_data ( col ) as (
       select .42      from dual union all
       select 1.2      from dual union all
       select 5        from dual union all
       select 2.222212 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; the SQL query is the one line below
select col, to_char(col, 'FM99999990.0999999999') as str from test_data;

     COL  STR
--------  --------
    0.42  0.42
     1.2  1.2
       5  5.0
2.222212  2.222212
```

Comment: it worked like a beauty. Thanks for the explanation. That made the solution even better.

Comment: Much appreciated!